# difference between url:server.php and url:server.php?q=1 in jqgrid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In jqgrid what is the difference between using,
 url : server.php and url : server.php?q=1
what does 'q' refers here.

Please clarify this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL part after the `?` is called `Query String` and the `q` will be available as variable with `GET ` and can be accessed using `$_GET['q']` in the `server.php` file.

Comment: I have used the example code which is given in jqgrid site, but in the server.php file this query string not get processed. and for drawing treegrid q=tree get passed but it also not get processed in server.php file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a query string variable. It's the same difference that exists between going to http://www.example.com/blah.php and http://www.example.com/blah.php?q=1 - i.e. it just passes an argument to the script via GET.